# interface that holds an array, use by different classes

Tags: java, interface

I have the following schema in UML:

```
Lecturer----implements-----Teaches (interface)
                             |   
Assistant-----implements-----|
```

so I want my interface to have a list of Courses that the teacher could lecture and that the assistant could do it also. So far I have the following code:

```
public interface Teaches{
      public String[] coursesList=new String[3];
}
```

//class Teacher enters couses into the coursesList like this:

```
public class Teacher{
      //////
      private int i;
      //currently omitting some arguments in the constructor
      public Teacher(){
              i=1;
      }
      addCourse(String course){
              coursesList[i]=course;
              i++;
}
```

the same procedure is done by the Assistant class, but when I print the data I have noticed that only lists me the courses from the teacher and not from assistant. Is there any way that situation does not happen?

Thanks

Comment: You can't have instance variables in an interface.

Comment: Interfaces shoul not carry attributes afaik.

Comment: What's the difference between a Lecturer and a Teacher?

Answer (score 2):

By default, all variables in an interface definition are `static` and `final`.  [Section 9.3 of the JLS covers this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3):

> Every field declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly public, static, and final. It is permitted to redundantly specify any or all of these modifiers for such fields.

That means that anything that implements the `Teaches` interface has access to the same `static` array `coursesList`.  Your `Teacher` object is likely overwriting the elements of the `coursesList` array.

You should change your `Teaches` interface into an abstract class, so that it can have its own instance variable `courseList` that each individual concrete subclass can access.

Comment: ... Or maybe create a base class _BaseTeacher_ (which may or may not be abstract).  The bottom line is _coursesList_ does **NOT** belong in an interface.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces cannot have data, just specfication.

If you want your classes to inherit a `String[] coursesList`, you'd rather make the class **abstract**